# Single mongodb index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having problems with unique in mongodb. I have an array of objects and in it I have an email, this email needs to be unique but I have the chance to have 0 or infinite employees.

How can he make it unique to allow this emptiness?

My employee is:

```
 employees: [{
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    second_name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    office: {
        type: String
    },
    access: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String, trim: true, index: {
            partialFilterExpression: {email: {$type: 'string'}}
        },
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    }
}]
```

This way he is accepting two e-mails.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try with Collection._ensureIndex('employees. email', {unique: 1, sparse: 1}) ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use what you're asking me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schema object you're passing may not work correctly because you are nesting 'unique' attribute into 'index' attribute, try something like this (it works as intended) :

```
employees: [{
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    second_name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    office: {
        type: String
    },
    access: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String, trim: true, index: {
            partialFilterExpression: {email: {$type: 'string'}}
        },
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    }
}]
```

Note: A unique index on an array field enforces that the same value cannot appear in the arrays of more than one document in the collection, but doesn't prevent the same value from appearing more than once in a single document's array. So you need to ensure uniqueness as you add elements to the array instead. ie you have to handling through your app logic.

Comment: It did not work its continuous option being able to create employees with same email

Comment: Added a note please check

Comment: I do not know if I understood very well what you informed because my native language is not English. I'm going to explain what I understood: Are you telling me that I can create within the same object employees with email alike but I will be blocked if I want to create another company with the employee with email equal to the other?

If this is it, I also tested it, in fact it is not blocking the email in any way, neither in officials of the same company nor in officials of different companies. I updated my question if you want to check how my index

Comment: hey you can achieve this on mongo constrain level. So whenever you are inserting new member you document you have to manually check. like: collection.db.findone({ "employee.email": "yournewmail@mail.com" }) if you already find the document you should return error message with already email exist else allow user to insert document.

Comment: This I had to do this with my api, now check if there is and if there is emito the email message already exists. Thank you. I will accept your response that the problem has been solved, but I had to do it differently.